# view sitching how to?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a mxml flex application where I have to launch a VideoPlayer on button click event. Any idea what solutions I can use to open a new "frame" or "view" (I'm not sure what the right terminology is) with the VideoPlayer playing a media clip so that it wouldn't interfere with the original "view"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is create a component (like a `TitleWindow`, `Group`, `Panel`, etc.) that has your VideoPlayer added to it and then use the `PopUpManager` to display it on screen when your button is clicked. Make sure you add a method to close the pop up when you're done with it.

Some links on the `PopUpManager` to get you started:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html
http://blog.flexexamples.com/category/popupmanager/
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/20/creating-custom-pop-up-windows-with-the-popupmanager-class-redux/

A (really) rough example:

```
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
    private var myVideoPlayerComponent:VideoPlayer;

    protected function btnHistory_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
      myVideoPlayerComponent = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, VideoPlayer, false);
      PopUpManager.centerPopUp(myVideoPlayerComponent);
    }
  ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Button label="Play" id="myButton" click="myButton_clickHandler(event)" />
```

Comment: One problem with this solution: not doable. Passing "Video" object to "createPopUp" causes compilation error: